# JavaMail to exchange losing addresses and messages

Tags: smtp, exchange-server, jakarta-mail

We have a wierd issue.  We have a process that pumps out Javamail messages to subscribing users based on events.  Sort of a workflow notification.  The messages are well documented in the database.

But rarely, users are reporting a message not arriving.  We went to the exchange logs and we can see some differences were the java process logged a message sent in the database, but exchange didn't see it.  We don't log messages in the database if Transport.send() returns an exception, but we would see it in the java logs, and we aren't.

What's more, a second symptom (maybe related, maybe not) is that some emails have fewer recipients than they are supposed to.  We logged 6 recipients on a particular event.  Moments later an identical event produced an email to the exact same recipients, yet the database shows all 6 were submitted to Javamail, but the exchange logs show only 3!?!  The first message, exchange said all 6.

The intermittent nature of this makes it infuriating, but just as much is that we've had three different developers look at the code and we can't see how the code is wrong in a way that results in no messages and such.

Does anyone have ideas?  Someone wondered if exchange might be suppressing things from our anonymous SMTP login in accordance with some SPAM rule, but why then do so many other messages go out freely.  There are way more successes than failures.

Comment: We probably need a lot more details to even guess at what could be going wrong.  Does all of this involve only a single application running on a single machine and sending messages directly to a single Exchange server, where all the users are retrieving their messages from that same Exchange server?

Comment: Yes, one application sends these events talking to one exchange server.  But users may be anywhere on the internet.  @BillShannon

Comment: You might find it helpful to enable [JavaMail session debugging](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug); the output will help you figure out whether your application really is sending the message to all the recipients you expect.  If it is, the problem is in your server.  If it is not, the problem is in your application.